# Laravel Relationship availability after save()

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, relationship

I'm building a simple timetracking App using Laravel 5 where I have two Laravel models, one called "User" and one called "Week"

The relationships are pretty simple:
Week.php:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

User.php:

```
function weeks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Week');
}
```

Now, the User.php file also has a simple helper / novelty function called "getCurrentWeek()" that, as the name suggests, returns the current week

```
function getCurrentWeek()
{
    $possibleWeek = $this->weeks->sortByDesc('starts')->all();
    if(count($possibleWeek) != 0)
    {
        return $possibleWeek[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My problem is: If I create the very first week for a user and attach / relate it to the user like so:

```
$week = new Week;

//Omitted: Setting so attributes here ...

$week->user_id = $user->id;
$weeks->save()
$user->weeks()->save($week);
```

And then call the `$user->getCurrentWeek();` method, that method returns `null`, although a new week has been created, is related to the user and has been saved to the database. In my mind, the expected behaviour would be for `getCurrentWeek()` to return the newly created week.
What am I misunderstanding about Eloquent here / doing just plain wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Relationship attributes are lazy loaded the first time they are accessed. Once loaded, they are not automatically refreshed with records that are added or removed from the relationship.

Since your `getCurrentWeek()` function uses the relationship attribute, this code will work:

```
$week = new Week;
// setup week ...
$user->weeks()->save($week);

// $user->weeks attribute has not been accessed yet, so it will be loaded
// by the first access inside the getCurrentWeek method
dd($user->getCurrentWeek());
```

But, this code will not work:

```
// accessing $user->weeks lazy loads the relationship
echo count($user->weeks);

// relate a new record
$week = new Week;
// setup week ...
$user->weeks()->save($week);

// $user->weeks inside the method will not contain the newly related record,
// as it has already been lazy loaded from the access above.
dd($user->getCurrentWeek());
```

You can either modify your `getCurrentWeek()` method to use the relationship method (`$this->weeks()`) instead of the attribute (`$this->weeks`), which will always hit the database, or you can reload the relationship (using the `load()` method) after adding or removing records.

Change the `getCurrentWeek()` method to use the relationship method `weeks()` (updated method provided by @Bjorn)

```
function getCurrentWeek()
{
    return $this->weeks()->orderBy('starts', 'desc')->first();
}
```

Or, refresh the relationship using the `load()` method:

```
// accessing $user->weeks lazy loads the relationship
echo count($user->weeks);

// relate a new record
$week = new Week;
// setup week ...
$user->weeks()->save($week);

// reload the weeks relationship attribute
$user->load('weeks');

// this will now work since $user->weeks was reloaded by the load() method
dd($user->getCurrentWeek());
```

Comment: `$thing->load('relationshipName')` was exactly what I needed. I was using lazy loaded relationships in a PDF that is generated directly after `save()` is called. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to @patricus answer...

After save/create/update, you can also empty all the cached relation data like so:

`$user->setRelations([]);`

Or selectively:

`$user->setRelation('weeks',[]);`

After that, data will be lazy loaded again only when needed:

`$user->weeks`

That way you can continue using lazy loading.

Comment: Great answer! (`eat this stackoverflow`)

Answer (score 0):

`$user->weeks()->save($week);` is not needed because you manually attached the week to the user by using `$week->user_id = $user->id;` and saving it.

You could actually rewrite the whole function to:

```
function getCurrentWeek()
{
    return $this->weeks->sortByDesc('starts')->first();
}
```

Or

```
function getCurrentWeek()
{
    return $this->weeks()->orderBy('starts', 'desc')->first();
}
```

### **Edit:**

I made a little proof of concept and it works fine like this:

> App\User.php

```
function weeks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Week');
}

function getCurrentWeek()
{
    return $this->weeks->sortByDesc('starts')->first();
}
```

> App\Week.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

> routes/web.php or App/Http/routes.php

```
Route::get('poc', function () {
    $user = App\User::find(1);
    $week = new App\Week;
    $week->user_id = $user->id;
    $week->starts = Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $week->save();
    return $user->getCurrentWeek();
});
```

> Result:

```
{
    id: 1,
    user_id: "1",
    starts: "2016-09-15 21:42:19",
    created_at: "2016-09-15 21:42:19",
    updated_at: "2016-09-15 21:42:19"
}
```

Comment: `$user->getCurrentWeek()` gets called directly after `$user->weeks()->save($week);` from my code above.  
I tried your method but now I'm getting an error.
`BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()`.
The error occurs at exactly that changed line. What exactly am I doing wrong here? I copy and pasted your exact code.

Comment: Hi @SvenE. I made a little proof of concept and both your way and my way worked fine. I attached all the code so you can compare it to yours. See my edit.

Comment: Try using get() instead of all()

Comment: Thanks so much @Björn, you poc-code helped me debug the problem :)